# Bootastrap - not support col-sm-6 in safari

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        col one   
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        col two   
    </div>
</div>
```

Hey guys, I'm using bootstrap for my website. But it's not working fine in safari. Do you guys know why is that happening? 
This ( Bootstrap v4.0.0 (https://getbootstrap.com) ) the version bootstrap i'm using. Please help thanks.

Comment: can you give some more information on what is not working ? what do you expect to happen an what is happening ?

Comment: Try upgrading to 4.1.3 I think earlier versions of 4 had issues

Comment: Yes Dirk, that two columns not aligning horizontally. It is broken and it aligned vertically..this is what is happening.

Comment: Hey Pete, let me try that. Thanks :)

Comment: Also make sure the browser width is larger than 576px otherwise the columns will be vertical

Comment: to add to what Pete wrote, if you want them to be next to each other on mobile, you have to add `.col-6` to each div

Comment: Hey Dirk and Pete, this is happening in desktop not in mobile. That's why I'm worried about.

Comment: what's the width on the device you're testing on?

Comment: It's Macbook Pro 2015 bro..

Comment: have you tested with other devices/browsers - e.g. Firefox/Chrome?

Comment: Yes only safari showing issues

Comment: @Coder95 have you tried inspecting the elements to see what css styles are being applied (if Safari has an inspector)

Comment: I think flex property is not supporting in safari..

Comment: class 'row' has flex property but that not working in safari.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex <-- shows safari **is** supported

Comment: Hey treyBake, is there any sites for checking website in iphone? I found an issue in my website only happening in some iphone. To find out the cause I need to inspect. So please say if anything exist. Thanks :)

Comment: there's ... I think it's called browserstack :)

Answer (score -1):

```
<!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Need to have this in your head on your HTML page.